# Get focusable element that are not in view

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, selector

I have a long list of divs with `a href` elements. The first 5 that are in the view return the element from the querySelector but the elements not in the view return null.

```
function getFocusableEl(elem) {
    let selector = `a[href="/${elem.screen_name}"]`
    return document.querySelector(selector);
}
```

How can I go to those elements and return their focusable element. This function is called on a simple for loop to get all elements on the page.

Comment: Can't see anything "magical" that this function does to filter focusable elements apart from just utilising a given selector.

Comment: @Viney yea the one that are not in the view return null but it may be intended behavior since they are no in view?

Comment: Not sure but I'd expect an anchor link very down the page to be focusable (I may be pressing tab on my keyboard) even when it's currently not in view. But again depends on what you are trying to do